# How to use src/groovy classes?

Tags: class, groovy, dns, src

I have a domain that needs to reference a class I created under the src / groovy directory. I'm following the above example: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain% 20Classes/embedded.html

```
===>
class Person { String name
 Country bornInCountry
 Country livesInCountry

 static embedded = ['bornInCountry', 'livesInCountry']
}

// If you don't want an associated table created for this class, either
// define it in the same file as Person or put Country.groovy under the
// src/groovy directory.
class Country {
 String iso3
 String name
}
```

According to the commented text, the Country class can stay in src / groovy directory. But when I create this class Country under this directory, it is no longer recognized by the Person class. The error "Groovy: unable to resolve class Country" is shown on the lines below:

```
Country bornInCountry
Country livesInCountry
```

How do I resolve this issue? Is there any way to make the reference using the import statement?

Thank you,

Pedro Gentil

Comment: Is `Country.groovy` moved to default package inside src/groovy? If yes, then put the class in an appropriate package and then import the same in the domain class.

Comment: Hello Clifford,
I realized my mistake.
The class may be created by New/Groovy Class...
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which package each of those classes are in.  If they are in the same package then you can do something like this:

Domain class:

```
// grails-app/domain/mypackage/Person.groovy
package mypackage

class Person {
    Country bornInCountry

    // ...
}
```

Non domain class:

```
// src/groovy/mypackage/Country.groovy
package mypackage

class Country {
    // ...
}
```

If they are not in the same package then you can solve the problem my adding an appropriate import statement to the `Person` class:

Domain class:

```
// grails-app/domain/mypackage/Person.groovy
package my package

import someotherpackage.Country

class Person {
    Country bornInCountry

    // ...
}
```

Non domain class:

```
// src/groovy/someotherpackage/Country.groovy
package someotherpackage

class Country {
    // ...
}
```

That should solve your compilation problem.

I hope that helps.